# 3d model geometry fix

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is possibe to fix geometry of model made in Photoscan? I've made a scan of XVII century ceiling joist which is straight and looked straight on the photos from which model was calculated of. Final model however bends and hangs down (looks like a delicate arch). Center of the model is also top of the arch.

Is there a way to make it straight again in blender without deteriorating dimensions and texture quality?

This is how the model looks in blender:
[image]
As You can clearly see, this is not the straightest element on earth...

In general it should be straight construction, just as in the reality. On the first glance model looked good, similar to the reality
[image]

Comment: we need to see the model... can you upload the blend via blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com?

Comment: Please add some images to illustrate your question.

Comment: Thanks for responding. You can download blend file through this link: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2358" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2358/)